# HTML5 Cache Manifest does not load ressources unless it is located at the root of the website?

Tags: html, caching, manifest, offline, cache-manifest

I have a website with a cache manifest described using

```
<html manifest="site.manifest">...</html>
```

The manifest is very simple :

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
/fira.jpg
/offline.php
FALLBACK:
/no.php /fallback.php
```

When my site is deployed under a domain root like:

```
http://localhost
```

I can see a GET request in Apache logs for site.manifest, all resources are loaded fine, manifest is working fine.

Now, If I deploy my web site under another context, like

```
http://localhost/other/
```

and hit this url, I can still see a GET request for site.manifest, however, no resources are loaded, and applicationCache contains 0 entries.

Is the Cache Manifest supposed to be server only from the root of a web site ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are using absolute URL's.  Try remoing the preceeding "/"

e.g.:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
fira.jpg
offline.php
```

or... you could use the correct absolute path -- /other/fira.jpg, etc.

I might be misunderstanding your issue - hopefully this helps :)

Greg